# Offer Letter included employment termination date which had passed

Tags: salary, contracts, employer-relations, canada

I work for several staffing/marketing agencies. My job is to go to retail location to demonstrate/sample products to increase awareness and ultimately increase sales.

Last year I was hired by a company (call them Cool Products). Cool Products hired me as a regular employee instead of a contractor. Though in the interview I was told to expect a lot of work, I did not receive any work for several months (I know this because I still got the emails even though I wasn't getting any work from them). For reasons I do not know, the person I report to got replaced several times in a short amount of time. Out of the blue I started receiving work from Cool Products. I still am interested in the work and it fit my schedule so I accepted it without much thought.

Today I noticed my Offer Letter said my employment with Cool Products was to terminate at the end of 2018. Obviously this hasn't happened. I looked at the offer letter because I was reminded of how after working a certain number of hours my pay was supposed to go up. My offer letter didn't specify the pay raise, but I have an email from a previous manager Cool Product's policy for pay raises.

I'm going to speak to my current manager to sort all this out. I really don't want to shoot my self in the foot. My main objective is to clearly know how much I should be getting paid. If it turns out I'm getting paid less than what the previous manager told me, how should I bring it up? Also, is it in my interest to bring up that my Offer Letter technically said my job should be terminated by now? Should I ask for a new contract? I guess someone could argue that since my previous contract terminated they can get away with paying me differently then what the manager at the time had said.

The current manager is very unclear and confusing both in phone calls and emails. I am not the only one who notices it. It's not a language barrier, but he tends to leave out important pieces of information or have his own definition of words that are different than most people's.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere neither had I. The offer letter states "Your employment will commence effective August 1, 2018 and terminate effective December 31, 2018". I'm in Canada.

Comment: I don't understand this... I've never heard of an arrangement like this where they hire a full-time employee and then don't give them any work at all for months.

Comment: I have heard of non-permanent positions before, however, they are typically more than 6 months.

Comment: I reread the Offer Letter and on several occasions it uses the word "employee" and never "contractor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you wrote: start looking for a new job (just in case), the situation seems messy.

Assuming they still pay you: Before talking to the company, ask a lawyer - if the job pays enough.

If the lawyer says that by ignoring the termination date, but paying you in a continued fashion they constructed another kind of contract (In Germany there would be "konkludentes Handeln", which could potentially establish a working contract, but **please ask a lawyer**), then you can decide if you try to talk to HR or not.

If that is not the case, then talking to HR will probably cause the salary payments to stop until you can get a new contract. Make sure that insurance and taxes are paid (look at the salary sheet), and then try to figure out what going on in the company (go to the next in line).

Comment: Good answer. In a lot of cases if someone continues to act as if a contract term does not apply they are essentially waiving it.